# Running ssh sudo asynchronously

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I'm trying to run a command with sudo on a remote machine. When I do it directly with

```
ssh -t -t -t myserver -q "sudo otheruser<<EOF
remotescript.sh
EOF"
```

it works fine, but if I add & at the end of the last line then it doesn't work. Why? How can I make it work?

I fact I'm running several such commands (to different servers) from a local script and save each output in a different file and would like them to run **asynchronously**.

Note: running ssh with otheruser@myserver is not an option. I really need to run sudo after I logged in.

Comment: I think you're missing the other `"`. Where should it have been placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **requiretty** from sudo config (/etc/sudoers) on the remote machine.

Also add the -f option to ssh which puts the command in background (man: "must be used when ssh is run in the background").

The "&" should not be needed when using -f.

E.g:

```
ssh -f -t -t -t myserver -q "sudo otheruser<<EOF
remotescript.sh
EOF"
```

Comment: There I also get "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo".

Comment: Ok, I missed that comment. Are you able to remove **requiretty** from sudo config (/etc/sudoers) on the server?

Comment: I've asked the sysadmins, but I'm not counting on it.

Comment: Can you run **su** instead of sudo?

Comment: I finally could remove requiretty :-) Still I would have been curious to see if there was any other way...

Comment: Being unable to recreate your problem my attempts to assist ends here I'm afraid. Hope you got your script working!

Answer (score 0):

Use expect to control your ssh. It could be used to give automated response to the remote shell. Most processes when ran asynchronously suspends itself or becomes suspended when it tries to read input from terminal since another foreground process (the main shell) is using it.

There's a post about ssh and expect lately here: https://superuser.com/questions/509545/how-to-run-a-local-script-in-remote-server-using-expect-and-bash-script

Also try to disown your process after placing it on the background with disown to keep it from job control. e.g.

```
whole_command &
disown
```

Changing its input to /dev/null might also help but it could hang forever if it really needs input from user.

```
whole_command <&- < /dev/null &
disown
```

Comment: I'm not sure I install expect as I don't own the machine. I've tried disown, but in the first case it doesn't seem to run anymore, and in the second it says: "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"